# submit a form to popup

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a table created with php-pear, and a jquery function that handles a click event to submit the cell information to a new form page. The jquery is this:

```
    var row = $this.parent('tr').contents('th:eq(0)').html();
    var departmentID = $(".deptSelect").val();  
    var headerObj = $(this).parents('.main').find('th').eq(colIndex);
    var toPass =   $.trim(headerObj.text());
    var picked = $("#picked").val();
    var testDate = new Date(picked + " " + row);
    var today = new Date();

    if (testDate < today)
    {
        if (roleID > 2)
        {
        alert("You Cannot Schedule a New Job in the Past!");
        }
        return;
    }
    var thisForm = '';

    if (roleID == 5)
    {
        thisForm = '../forms/tentativeJobForm.php';
    }
    else
    {
        thisForm ='../forms/newJobForm.php';
    }

    var f = document.createElement("form");
    f.setAttribute('class','jobTime');
    f.setAttribute('method','post');
    f.setAttribute('action',thisForm);

    var iii = document.createElement('input');
    iii.setAttribute('type','hidden');
    iii.setAttribute('name','departmentID');
    iii.setAttribute('value',departmentID);
    f.appendChild(iii);

    var i = document.createElement('input');
    i.setAttribute('type','hidden');
    i.setAttribute('name','sTime');
    i.setAttribute('value',picked + " " + row);
    f.appendChild(i);

    var ii = document.createElement('input');
    ii.setAttribute('type','hidden');
    ii.setAttribute('name','ast');
    ii.setAttribute('value',toPass);
    f.appendChild(ii);

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
    if (roleID > 2)
    $('.jobTime').submit;
    else
    return;
});
```

This works in essence, but my users have complained about not seeing the calendar page when they schedule new jobs and it conflicts with another job already scheduled. My new requirement is that the resulting conflict page opens as a popup window. Not an alert that there was a conflict, but the original form with the conflicting information. The above form is submitted to my php page, and the following function handles conflicts:

```
function checkRows($stmt, $msg=NULL, $params=NULL)//, $updatedInfo=NULL)
{
    if ($stmt != NULL)
    {
        $rows_affected = sqlsrv_rows_affected($stmt);
        if ($rows_affected > 0)
        {
            $starting = new DateTime($params[5]);
            $ending = new DateTime($params[6]);
            $starting = date_format($starting,'m/d/Y h:i a');
            $ending = date_format($ending,'m/d/Y h:i a');

            echo "Job:" . $params[0] . " was Successfully Scheduled for $starting to $ending<br>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $userSTime = new DateTime($params[0]);
        $userSTime = date_format($userSTime,'m/d/Y h:i a');

        $userETime = new DateTime($params[1]);
        $userETime = date_format($userETime,'m/d/Y h:i a');     
        $_SESSION['jbNum'] = $params[2];
        $_SESSION['asset'] = $params[4];
        $_SESSION['userSTime'] = $userSTime;
        $_SESSION['userETime'] = $userETime;
        $_SESSION['userDesc'] = trim($params[3]);
        $_SESSION['conJbNum'] = $msg['JobNum'];
        $_SESSION['conSTime'] = date_format($msg['StartTime'], 'm/d/Y h:i a');
        $_SESSION['conETime'] = date_format($msg['EndTime'], 'm/d/Y h:i a');
        $_SESSION['dueDate'] = $params[5];
        $_SESSION['comment'] = $params[6];
        $_SESSION['destination'] = $params[7];
        $_SESSION['jStat'] = $params[8];

        if ($_SESSION['recurring'] == 'n')
        {
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=../forms/newJobForm.php' target = 'mainFrame'/>";
        exit;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Scheduling for Job:" . $params[2] ." failed for $userSTime to $userETime<br>";
        }
    }

}
```

When a conflict is encountered the original form is opened up with the new information from the session variables. How can I open the form in a popup window? I know this shouldn't be too difficult but I cannot get it to work. FYI target='_blank' has been suggested but only opens a new tab. That won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the checkRows function I had to change:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=../forms/newJobForm.php' target = 'mainFrame'/>";
exit;
```

To:

```
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=../pages/schedule.php' target = 'mainFrame'/>";
    echo '<script>window.open("../forms/newJobForm.php",null,"height=550,width=900,status=yes, scrollbars=1, toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");</script>';
    echo "<script>window.close()</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like a dialog box? If so, you can use jQueryUI's .dialog() feature.

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: No not the dialog box. I need it to open the full form so they can alter the form while looking at the calendar information and resubmit it.

Comment: jQuery Dialog boxes allow for forms and form submissions. If you're not familiar, it's really just a div inside a stylized framework to display it as a popup. Does that not meet your needs because the form has to be submitted without reloading the calendar page?

Comment: Perhaps a new tab of a size of your choosing would be sufficient? If so, [here's a link](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=27140) discussing how to do it.

Comment: I figured out the solution and will be posting shortly. Now I have to figure out how to close the popup after the new form is submitted.